# Bash script on OSX that switches between root and user

Tags: macos, bash, rvm

I'm attempting to write a script that, among other things, installs rvm. In order to do this the script is run as root (sudo setup.sh) where setup.sh calls a subscript that installs rvm. However, in order to install rvm I need to be the user, so I want to switch from being root to being the user. I do this like this:

In setup.sh:

```
# Do some stuff as root

# Install rvm
sudo -u $SUDO_USER source path/to/rvm_install/script
sudo -u install_rvm
```

However, when I do this I get this error from bash:

```
sudo: source: command not found
```

If I do `which source` I get nothing as either root or as the $SUDO_USER. However, I can source the .bash_profile, without errors, for example. And, I can man source and there's a manual so I know that source is installed.

How can I switch to $SUDO_USER and still get bash to recognize my subscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type source` will tell you that `source` is a shell builtin, not an external command. Shell builtins can only be used within a shell, not through external tools like `sudo`.

If you want to execute your subscript and throw away any environment variables set, you can just do

```
sudo -u $SUDO_USER bash path/to/rvm_install/script
```

If the install_rvm command requires variables or functions defined in path/to/rvm_install/script, you can use

```
sudo -u $SUDO_USER bash -c 'source path/to/rvm_install/script; install_rvm'
```

Comment: works like a charm! Thanks for the helpful explanation and sudo command.